# How can I use the iksolver.cpp

Tags: ros, ik, roscpp, ikfast

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I generated the file to calculate the inverseKinematics with IKFast.
How can I use this file, to solve the IK from a cpp in ROS?
I can not find anything about that.
I'm using the solver TranslationDirection5D

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/160036/how-can-i-use-the-iksolver.cpp/) by [Bastbeat](https://answers.ros.org/users/12796/bastbeat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 131 on 2014-05-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bastbeat](https://answers.ros.org/users/12796/bastbeat/) on 2014-05-03**:
I tried to compile the cpp anyway, to test it. And when I run it, it shows an error.
Usage: ./ik r00 r01 r02 t0 r10 r11 r12 t1 r20 r21 r22 t2 free0 ...
input: ./compute2 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
output: Failed to get ik solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The orientation never can be "0 0 0" in all the cases.
The correct input should be (for example): ./compute2 1 0 0 0.1 0 1 0 0.2 0 0 1 0.3

And you can use the generated iksolver.cpp, using it like a normal include.
Respect to the use, there is a great example:
ikfastdemo.cpp: https://github.com/davetcoleman/clam/blob/master/clam_ik/src/ikfastdemo.cpp

There you can find many ways to use the solver (IK, FK...)

---

Originally posted by [Bastbeat](https://answers.ros.org/users/12796/bastbeat/) with karma: 131 on 2014-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JarvisRobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/28749/jarvisrobot/) on 2017-07-24**:
It still doesn't work..